# Draggable div with gmap inside dont work on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I want to make a div draggable, so that I can drag an gmap (like an widget). I don't want to drag the content of the gmap.

In my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obdelix/uk1fmvn8/19) it works on computer browser but don't on a mobile browser. That's my simple code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),

        zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
     map.setOptions({"draggable" : false });
    $(function() {
        $( ".drag" ).draggable();
    });
}
```

What can I do?

I'm using jQuery UI Touch Punch for react on touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI doesn't currently support touch events. You can however use libraries to accomplish the behavior you're looking for. [Jquery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) is a good example.

Comment: Hello Jeremy, i used in this case Jquery UI Touch Punch.